# Объясните что происходит в методе Save и Download

Tags: java

```java
import java.io.*;
    
public class Serialize implements Serializable {

  public static void Save(Bank bank) throws IOException {
    File out1 = new File("C:\\Users\\sveta\\IdeaProjects\\untitled\\src\\Lr3\\file.dat");
    FileOutputStream Out1 = new FileOutputStream(out1);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(Out1);
    objectOutput.writeObject(bank);
    Out1.close();
    objectOutput.close();
  }


  public static void Download(Bank bank) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream In1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\sveta\\IdeaProjects\\untitled\\src\\Lr3\\file.dat");
    ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(In1);
    Bank bank1 = (Bank)objectInput.readObject();
    String name = bank1.getName();
    int accounts = bank1.getSize();
    int atm = bank1.getATMs();
    System.out.println("Банк: " + name);
    System.out.println("Количество счетов: " + accounts);
    System.out.println("Количество Банкоматов: " + atm);
    In1.close();
    objectInput.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробую объяснить простым языком. **Save** метод сохраняет объект bank в файл "C:\Users\sveta\IdeaProjects\untitled\src\Lr3\file.dat" с помощью классов FileOutputStream и ObjectOutputStream. FileOutputStream используется для записи байтов в файл, а ObjectOutputStream используется для сериализации объекта bank и записи его в файл.

**Download** метод загружает объект из файла "C:\Users\sveta\IdeaProjects\untitled\src\Lr3\file.dat" с помощью классов FileInputStream и ObjectInputStream. FileInputStream используется для чтения байтов из файла, а ObjectInputStream используется для десериализации объекта и создания объекта Bank. Затем информация о банке, количество счетов и количество банкоматов извлекается из объекта и выводится на консоль.